# Python, order and list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I need help with python. (and please excuse my English)
I have an order of list: from [0,1,2,3,4,5] to [5,4,3,2,1,0] (this is kind of an alphabetic order with the "letters" 0, 1 , 2 , 3 ,4 and 5). For example what follows [0,1,2,3,4,5] is [0,1,2,3,5,4], then it's [0,1,2,4,3,5] and it goes on. Be careful you have to use each letter once to form a list.

And basically my program give me a list such as [1,5,0,3,4,2] and I would like to have the corresponding number in my order. 
Find this out and I you will save my day ! Thanks :)

Comment: Try `shuffle` for in-place shuffling of a list

Answer (score 0):

I think you have `permutations`, and need the `index`:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> L = list(permutations(range(6),6))  # Generate the list
>>> len(L)
720
>>> L[0]            # First item
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
>>> L[-1]           # Last item
(5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0)
>>> L.index((0,1,2,3,4,5)) # Find a sequence
0
>>> L.index((5,4,3,2,1,0))
719
>>> L.index((1,5,0,3,4,2))
219
```

Note the list as generated is a list of tuples, not list of lists.  If you want list of lists:

```
>>> L = [list(x) for x in permutations(range(6),6)]
>>> L.index([1,5,0,3,4,2])
219
```